# Iterate through a range of dates in Javascript

Tags: javascript

For the last few days I was struggling with iterating through a range of dates. I was using following piece of code to test:

```
var current_date = new Date("2014-08-01");
var end_date = new Date("2014-10-31");
var end_date_time = end_date.getTime();

while (current_date.getTime() <= end_date_time) {
    document.write(current_date + '<br>');
    current_date.setDate(current_date.getDate()+1);
}
```

To me it looks correct, but there's a problem. It's missing the last day. I was turning this code around, used a for- loop, defined new Date within loop and all the things you can imagine. One thing stayed the same. Last day missing!

By curiosity I used following format to create the Dates:

```
var current_date = new Date("08/01/2014");
var end_date = new Date("10/31/2014");
```

And to my surprise, it worked as expected. Now I'm wondering if this is a normal behaviour or a bug in Date?

I would be thankfull, if someone can enlighten me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

that is because there was a change in time, check that the first days are in GMT Daylight Time and the lasts in  (GMT Standard Time)

so your code better to use UTC

```
var current_date = new Date("2014-08-01");
current_date = new Date(current_date.getUTCFullYear(), current_date.getUTCMonth(), current_date.getUTCDate(),  current_date.getUTCHours(), current_date.getUTCMinutes(), current_date.getUTCSeconds());
var end_date = new Date("2014-10-31");
end_date = new Date(end_date.getUTCFullYear(), end_date.getUTCMonth(), end_date.getUTCDate(),  end_date.getUTCHours(), end_date.getUTCMinutes(), end_date.getUTCSeconds());
var end_date_time = end_date.getTime();


while (current_date <= end_date) {
    document.write(current_date + '<br>');
    current_date.setDate(current_date.getDate()+1);
}
```

Comment: Change in time means a change in Date function? I'm willing to accept your answer. But can you explain me why its working with the mentioned format 'd/m/Y' and fails while using 'Y-m-d'? Dont get me wrong, I'm not picky. I just want to know why things are like they are.

Comment: Sorry I cannot help you with that. I have learned from experience that when working with dates, work with utc and render in the format/timezone you have to.